# sequence of the ids selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a piece of jquerty code where the table structure is like this?:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><button class="selectItems"><i class="fa faplus"></i></button</td></tr> 1
    <tr><td><button class="selectItems"><i class="fa faplus"></i></button</td></tr> 2
    <tr style="color:red"><td></tr> 3
    <tr><td><button class="selectItems"><i class="fa faplus"></i></button</td></tr> 4 
    <tr><td><button class="selectItems"><i class="fa faplus"></i></button</td></tr> 5
</table>




$(".SelectItems").click(function() {
 var ele = $(this);
 var findprev = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
 if (!(findprev).find('td button i').hasClass('fa-trash') == true) {
            alert("Bad data");
            return;
        }
 });
```

what i am trying here is if my parent is: 3 and if i select 5, it should show me an error that it is invalid sequence. so i had to select 4 before i select 5.

same is the case above: i can select 2 before 1 to continue sequence , cannot select 1

but when i select 4, it should skip the parent check because that is where i am tying it to, so if i select 2 after 4, it should consider it a sequence because 3 is parent

Comment: Can you please use Stack Snippets (icon in editor looks like `<>`) to create a [mcve]? Right now, that code won't work because it lacks a `<table>` tag to wrap the rows and no use of `$` or `jQuery` into which to pass `findprev` (nor a definition of `findprev`).

Comment: let me update it

Comment: There is a misunderstanding about the word "parent" here I think.

Comment: well parent can be considered as the one where i want to start and that does not have the button assigned to it, so i call it as parent but it can be referred to as base

Comment: In HTML, "parent" is the element that contains another one.

Comment: Ok... Now it's unclear about the sequence... Why a particular sequence is supposed to be valid? There is no `.fa-trash` anywhere...

Comment: I fixed the noumerous markup errors and assumed things about your script in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZjJWNN?editors=1111). Now what about the sequence?

Comment: yes because if the fa-plus will be clicked it will become fa-trash and so on, but i want that the first one selected should be after or before parent

Comment: Th Sequence is: Assume parent is 3, I should be select either 4 and continuous and if backwards from 2 onward, cannot skip

Comment: You should try to do that `.fa-plus` turning into a `.fa-trash` from my codepen first... There is obviously not enought effort in there. I won't code thing that aren't there. -- I already voted that to be closed as unclear.

Comment: I updated the codepen to http://prntscr.com/kb2n5m, so technically i had enabled the 2 and 5 as selected as it should be able to select upword one by one or downward one by one. the next picture is showing invalid sequence 

http://prntscr.com/kb2nun

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sequence = [];
        
        $('.parent').on('click',function(e) {
          sequence.push($(this).text());
            $(this).css('color', 'green');
        });
        
        $('.child').on('click',function(e) {
           if (jQuery.inArray(($(this).parent().parent().parent().children('.btn').text()).toString(), sequence) !='-1') {
               sequence.push($(this).text());
               $(this).css('color', 'green');
           }else{
               alert('Bad Data');
               sequence = [];
               $(this).removeAttr('style');
           }
        });
         
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><button class="btn parent"><i class="fa faplus"></i>1</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn parent"><i class="fa faplus"></i>2</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn parent"><i class="fa faplus"></i>3</button>
        <ul>
            <li><button class="btn child"><i class="fa faplus"></i>4</button></li>
            <li><button class="btn child"><i class="fa faplus"></i>5</button></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there anything specific that is not clear? If you want I'll explain. The code is quite speaking.

Comment: I'm not OP. I have no idea what your code is supposed to do, why you're doing what you're doing, and why you didn't go another way (if there is another sane way). A code dump doesn't help anybody.

Comment: can we use the structure i have, i cannot use ul > li

Comment: There is no sense of nesting, losing the parent-child meaning